# MFC No Visible Border/Frame Style

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, docking

I am trying to have multiple dockablepane classes in an MFC app. The problem is I cannot have them show their frames/border when they are in docked condition and as the result, you cannot detect them or figure where they are separated when they are both docked.

I am creating tow classes from the CDockablePane class.

```
class MFCDockPanelLeft : public CDockablePane
```

then in Mainframe, I am trying to creat them with the CBRS_BORDER_ANY or WS_THICKFRAME, but it will keep hiding the border when it is docked.

```
UINT style = WS_CHILD | CBRS_LEFT | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI | CBRS_BORDER_BOTTOM | CBRS_BORDER_LEFT | CBRS_BORDER_ANY;
DWORD dwTabbedStyle = AFX_CBRS_REGULAR_TABS | CBRS_BORDER_ANY;
DWORD dwControlBarStyle = AFX_DEFAULT_DOCKING_PANE_STYLE | CBRS_BORDER_ANY ;

dock_paneTop->Create(strTitle, this, CRect(0, 0, 200, 400), TRUE, ID_VIEW_PANETOP,style, dwTabbedStyle, dwControlBarStyle);
```

Is there a way to have the border or some visual line to show the area that the two windows are splitting.

[image]

Edit:
After Using visual Manager and for exampl using MS office 2007 style, the borders will be added:

[image]

Comment: Try [CreateDefaultPaneDivider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdockablepane-class?view=vs-2019#createdefaultpanedivider)

Comment: I could bot get border from it. It is probably related to actual dividing panes  not bordering them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own PaneDivider class (derived from CPaneDivider) and customize its visuals.
Or maybe easier to implement: You can create a custom VisualManager class (derived from CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007) if you use the Feature Pack.

If one of these approaches could match your request, I can give you some more hints. Please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, You are exactly right. with VisualManager, it does create them with nice borders. 

If you select (for example) MS Office 2007, it will have the nice borders and if you select Windows Xp style it will look like my original style with no borders!

It would be great if you can give some hints on how I can do this through the CPaneDivider route.

Comment: Btw. you can also change the width of the borders by setting the static value CPaneDivider::m_nDefaultWidth.